# JEXL : How to parse a recursive expression

Tags: java, jexl

Having a JEXL expression, How can I parse it in order to dynamically add to JEXL context all the involved variables?

Example : Initial Expression:

```
Initial Expression = $VAR1 + $VAR2
```

VAR1 and VAR2 are other expressions

```
$VAR1 = 123 + 45
$VAR2 = 67 + 89
```

Even more VAR1 can have another depth level :

```
$VAR1 = 123 + 45 + $VAR3
```

So, before evaluate Initial expression , I need to add into the context VAR1 and VAR2 and VAR3, How can I do it in a dynamic way?

It is possible to use a JEXL parser? Or by catching the JEXL exception? Can you provide an example?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to worry about it at all. JEXL handles it.

But, first and foremost thing, you should use **Script evaluator**, instead of **Expression evaluator**. Script evaluators do handle multiple statements nicely as well as support complex looping syntax.

See [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/apidocs/org/apache/commons/jexl3/package-summary.html)

> **JexlScript**
>
> These allow you to use multiple statements and you can use variable
>   assignments, loops, calculations, etc. More or less what can be
>   achieved in Shell or JavaScript at its basic level. The result from
>   the last command is returned from the script.
>
> **JxltEngine.Expression**
>
> These are ideal to produce "one-liner" text, like a 'toString()' on
>   steroids. To get a calculation you use the EL-like syntax as in
>   ${someVariable}. The expression that goes between the brackets behaves
>   like a JexlScript, not an expression. You can use semi-colons to
>   execute multiple commands and the result from the last command is
>   returned from the script. You also have the ability to use a 2-pass
>   evaluation using the #{someScript} syntax.

Now, try below:

```
String script =     
            "var var1 = 123 + 45;"
        +   "var var2 = 67 + 89;"
        +   "var var = var1 + var2;"
        +   "return var;";

JexlContext jexlContext = new MapContext();

JexlEngine jexlEngine=new JexlBuilder().create();

System.out.println(jexlEngine.createScript(script).execute(jexlContext); // 134
```